# if-else statement undefined object

Tags: jquery, json

Some weird stuff is happening:

JSON:

```
{
    "all": {
        "id": [
            "64",
            "65"
        ],
        "code": [
            "AqCeTZ3Q",
            "CTRtldIw"
        ],
        "file_match": [
            "voorbeeld.php",
            "Handeler.rar"
        ],
        "file_size": [
            "30",
            "146693"
        ],
        "expire": [
            "1386543600",
            "1386543600"
        ],
        "ip": [
            "dada",
            ""
        ],
        "can_used": [
            "0",
            "1"
        ],
        "opmerking": [
            "",
            ""
        ]
    },
    "id": [
        "65"
    ],
    "active": {
        "code": [
            "CTRtldIw"
        ],
        "file_match": [
            "Handeler.rar"
        ],
        "file_size": [
            "146693"
        ],
        "expire": [
            "1386543600"
        ],
        "ip": [
            ""
        ],
        "can_used": [
            "1"
        ],
        "opmerking": [
            ""
        ]
    },
    "expired": {
        "id": [
            "64"
        ],
        "code": [
            "AqCeTZ3Q"
        ],
        "file_match": [
            "voorbeeld.php"
        ],
        "file_size": [
            "30"
        ],
        "expire": [
            "1386543600"
        ],
        "ip": [
            "dada"
        ],
        "can_used": [
            "0"
        ],
        "opmerking": [
            ""
        ]
    }
}
```

Script 1 (works):

```
function update() {
    var value = document.getElementById("chooser").value;
    $.ajax({
    url: "./json.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, value) {

                alert(data.all.id);

            }
        });
    }
```

Output: alert with a value: 64,65. Correct!

Script 2: (works not, I dont know why.)

```
function update() {
    var value = document.getElementById("chooser").value;
    $.ajax({
    url: "./json.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data, value) {
            if(value == all) {
                alert(data.all.id);
            } else if (value == active) {
                alert(data.active.id);
            } else { // expired
                alert(data.expired.id);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: all is not defined. (when value == all)

So, I have no idea why the script is broken when I add an statement. Does anybody know why this is not working and how to fix it?

Comment: need to use browser console to look at errors thrown....`all` and `active` are undefined and these errors will show in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the value retrieved before the ajax in the ajax handler you have to not have any other variables with the same name in its scope to override it, i.e. remove the `value` parameter from the success handler.

```
function update() {
    var value = document.getElementById("chooser").value;
    $.ajax({
    url: "./json.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
            if(value == "all") {
                alert(data.all.id);
            } else if (value == "active") {
                alert(data.active.id);
            } else { // else expired
                alert(data.expired.id);
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on your json. 'all' can only be referenced through 'data.all' otherwise script is treating it as a  variable, which is undeclared.